# How do I build a regular expression from an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, regex

Using Ruby 2.4, how do I build a regular expression using an array that contains strings?  I have

```
TOKENS = %w(to - &).freeze
```

I want to build a regular expression that says, match at least one number, an arbitrary of breaking or non-breaking space, and then one of the strings from my array.  I tried teh below, with the resulting error

```
2.4.0 :014 > "abc" =~ /^\d+[[:space:]]*#{Regexp.escape(TOKENS)}/
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Array into String
    from (irb):14:in `escape'
    from (irb):14
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

An example of something that would match would be

```
2 to blah
```

and something that would not match would be

```
& no way
```

Comment: Replace `Regexp.escape` with `Regexp.union`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Regexp.union`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Regexp.html#method-c-union):

> Return a Regexp object that is the union of the given *patterns*, i.e., will match any of its parts. The *patterns* can be Regexp objects, in which case their options will be preserved, or Strings. If no *patterns* are given, returns `/(?!)/`.

Note if there are any special chars, they will get escaped to match literal chars.

So, use

```
"abc" =~ /^\d+[[:space:]]*#{Regexp.union(TOKENS)}/
                                   ^^^^^
```

In Ruby 2.4, you may use `.match?`:

```
 /^\d+[[:space:]]*#{Regexp.union(TOKENS)}/.match?('abc')
                           ^^^^^           ^^^^^^
```

Comment: Is there a performance difference between using "=~" as opposed to "match?"?

Comment: Dave, surely not, considering that `r.match?(str)` is nothing more than `str =~ r ? true : false` or `!!(str =~ r)`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Seeing as how `Regexp#match?` doesn't produce any captures, set special variables, etc, it's not unreasonable to think it may in fact have different performance characteristics since it might plausibly be optimized by skipping certain steps of the normal match process. I'm not saying it _does_ have those performance characteristics, mind, that would depend on the C implementation.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Indeed, the introduction of `Regexp#match?` is explicitly listed as a performance enhancement in [the release notes for 2.4.0](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2016/12/25/ruby-2-4-0-released/), as it avoids object allocations performed by other methods such as `Regexp#match` and `=~`.

Comment: @philomory, good points, and thanks for the clarification. I was addressing the question of whether `match?` is as efficient as `=~`, overlooking the question of whether `match?` might be more efficient.

Comment: @Dave: see philomory's comment and link: "`Regexp#match?` *executes a regexp match without creating a back reference object and changing $~ to reduce object allocation*"